# Uniform convergence of the sequence $f_n(x)=f(x+1/n)$ for uniformly continuous $f$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, uniform-continuity

Let $f$ be a uniformly continuous real-valued function on $(-\infty, +\infty)$, and for each $n\in I$ let $f_n(x)=f\left(x+\frac{1}{n}\right)$.

> Prove that $\{f_n\}_{1}^{\infty}$ converges uniformly on $(-\infty, +\infty)$ to $f$.

I have no idea to prove this.

Comment: You need to show that  $|f(x+1/n)-f(x)|$ can be made uniformly small (with respect to $x$) provided $n$ is large enough. Now think about what uniform continuity gives you.

Comment: @David Mitra; Thank you so much for your fast response and the clue that you gave me.

Answer (score 4):

$f$ is uniformly continuous  on  $\mathbb{R}$, so for  $\forall \epsilon >0 \ \exists \delta >0; \ \forall x,\ y\in\mathbb{R} \ \text{if }\ |y-x|<\delta \Rightarrow|f(y)-f(x)|<\epsilon . \ \ (*)$

Now for this $\delta$, there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{N}<\delta$. Hence  for $\forall n\geq N$ and $\forall x\in\mathbb{R},\ y:=x+\frac{1}{n}$ we have $|y-x|=|(x+\frac{1}{n})-x|=\frac{1}{n}<\delta$. As a result by $(*)$, we have $|f(y)-f(x)|=|f(x+\frac{1}{n})-f(x)|<\epsilon$.

This prove your problem. Since, with my notations, for $\forall \epsilon>0 \  \exists N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for $\forall x\in\mathbb{R} \ $ and $\forall n\geq N$, we have:

$|f_n(x)-f(x)|=|f(x+\frac{1}{n})-f(x)|=|f(y)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ .

Answer (score 0):

You have to show that given $\epsilon>0$ you can find an $k\in \Bbb{N}$ depending on $\epsilon$ only such that $$|f_n(x)-f(x)|=|f\left(x+\frac{1}{n}\right)-f(x)|<\epsilon \quad \forall n\ge k $$ Now use uniform continuity to show that above inequality is true.